# How do I process an icon on the server? I cannot update the icon

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

**icon file**

"I'm trying to implement the ability to update the avatar. I enable the 'editing' mode, and a form for updating the avatar appears. I upload the file, but it doesn't go into my trait and is not saved."

I suspect that the problem is that the image simply does not go to the server

```
    <img :src="previewImage || (data.icon ? `/storage/${data.icon}` : '/storage/images/logo/no-logo.png')" alt="Logo"
                         class="object-cover rounded-full" style="width: 6rem; height: 6rem">
                    <input type="file" id="icon" class="hidden" ref="file" @change="handleLogoUpload">  
export default {
data() {
    return {
        editing: false,
        previewImage: null,
    }
},
props: {
    data: Object
}, 
methods: {
    browse(){
      this.$refs.file.click()
    },
    handleLogoUpload() {
        const fileInput = this.$refs.file;
        const file = fileInput.files[0];

        if (file) {
            this.previewImage = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            this.data.icon = file
        }
    },

     saveChanges() {
        try {
            this.$inertia.put(`/admin/location/${this.data.id}`, this.data);
            this.stopEditing();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error saving changes:', error);
        }
    },
```

**Controller**

```
  public function update(UpdateLocationsRequest $request, Location $location): 
  RedirectResponse
{
    $validatedData = $request->validated();

    $location->update($validatedData);

    $this->processImage($request, $location, 'icon');

    $location->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Location updated');
}
```

**traits**

```
     trait HandlesImages
     {
        public function processImage(Request $request, Model $model, string $fieldName): void
{
    if ($request->hasFile($fieldName)) {

        $imageFile = $request->file($fieldName);
        $imagePath = $imageFile->store('public/' . $fieldName);
        if ($imagePath) {
            $model->$fieldName = Str::replaceFirst('public/', '', $imagePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more details. Does the record get updated in the database? Does the process throw an error?

Comment: If you've modified the image, but saved it to the same filename, then it's going to be cached. If you modify the content of a static file you should also modify the filename to properly indicate that the new file content should be fetched.

Comment: Check if it is reaching the `controller`, if not check if it is reaching the `UpdateLocationRequest`

Comment: @SyncroIT no one error. also no create record in the database